# Выдает ошибку когда пытается загрузить файл. ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, jquery

Верхняя строка работает нижняя нет. Притом что нижняя строка видит гифку. Она отображается на поле слева от кода в редакторе. Собираю через Webpack

```
var url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=1qoOlQyVQvwiV2_P6XbkPPhPnQ0BXXhyb";
var url = "../../images/CST/Vector-Arrow_ANIM_GREEN2.gif";

$("#multyArrowsReversUp").css("backgroundImage", `url(${url}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Почему у вас 2 раза объявление одной и той же переменной ? Редактор кода не ругается?
Попробуйте проверить правильность второго пути через DevTools и изменить название переменной 
For example:

```
var url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=1qoOlQyVQvwiV2_P6XbkPPhPnQ0BXXhyb";
var urlGif = "../../images/CST/Vector-Arrow_ANIM_GREEN2.gif";

$("#multyArrowsReversUp").css("backgroundImage", `url(${url}`);

$("#multyArrowsReversUp").css("backgroundImage", `url(${urlGif}`);
```

Comment: Я спецально для примера так написал. Проблема в том что если мы оставляем строку `var urlGif = "../../images/CST/Vector-Arrow_ANIM_GREEN2.gif";` То картинка не загружается. А в случае с `var url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=1qoOlQyVQvwiV2_P6XbkPPhPnQ0BXXhyb";` карптинка загружает.

Comment: Ну картинку с гугла он может взять, но локальную почему-то не хочет. Возможно всё же что-то с путем не так?